# Phone's camera vs browser's camera image quality

Tags: javascript, stream, webrtc, getusermedia

I built a webapp to capture an image using `getUserMedia()`,
but the quality of the image is not so good, it's a little blurry!. I tried to take the picture via my phone's camera and there is a big difference!

I like to know why taking the picture from browser is not as good as taking it from the phone's camera! and if it's possible, how can it be done to get the image captured via browser (`getUserMedia()`) with the best quality?

```js
capture.addEventListener('click', () => {
  c.style.display = "flex";
  c.width = video.outerWidth();
  c.height = video.outerHeight();
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  video.style.display = "none";
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: gUM varies enough from device to device and browser to browser that we need more information to help you. I suppose you've tried the "official" snapshot demo at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/ and gotten similar results to those in your question.  What device? What camera? What browser (on what device)?  Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these lines

```
  c.width = video.videoWidth;
  c.height = video.videoHeight;
```

Then your canvas will have the same resolution as the captured video.  You can use CSS to scale the canvas appropriately for display, and most browsers do a good job of making the scaled display look good.